# Replacing alert file in app package contents?

Tags: macos, applications, audio, music, software

Probably a strange question - not sure if this is possible or not....I purchased a utility app for Mac recently to manage my NAS and external hard drives.  Works great, only thing that's **really** annoying is the music/finished "beep" it plays as the "confirmation" beep.  I'm fine with regular notification alerts, but this gets very frustrating after a while.  I could, of course silence the speakers, but with how frequently I use the app, it will often come on without me remembering to silence it (and it's just plain inconvenient, if I want to listen to something else.)

ANYWAY.....I finally had enough of it and went into the "Package contents" of the app to locate the music file, which wasn't difficult (it is a `.mov` file.) I thought that simply deleting the file would fix the issue, but then the app wouldn't open (said it couldn't load all resources.)  Next thing I tried was replacing the music file with an inaudible track (same length, etc...) still didn't work.  It seems to only accept the original audio file.  Is there any way to remove/replace this?  There's no option to silence it in the (scarce) Preferences panel.  Ordinarily I would find another app, but this has worked much better than any alternatives I've found (aside from the mentioned issue. :P)

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm mainly puzzled as to why a sound file would be saved as a .mov, rather than wav/aif etc

Comment: @Tetsujin no idea....but .mov files can be used for just audio on OS X.  Not sure why either.